# Peer node is not starting in commercial paper samples

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to run the  ./start.sh as specified in the tutorial https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/tutorial/commercial_paper.html

I am getting the error:

Error response from daemon: Container 3098af67969c5388c78f3ed97b9941ac637c7292342cd90e109a6c5e3ef2a5ea is not running

Basically Peer node container is not getting up. Can you please help me?

This Ubuntu VM is hosted in Cloud

Please check the peer node container Logs:

root@UbuntuVM:/home/NagaRajeshK/hyperledgerdev/fabric-samples/basic-network# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
e60a0578eae4        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"                3 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                       orderer.example.com
c1c5510432f5        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   3 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                       ca.example.com
9cf315b8946c        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   3 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp   couchdb
root@UbuntuVM:/home/NagaRajeshK/hyperledgerdev/fabric-samples/basic-network# docker logs 3098af67969c
2019-04-05 13:51:59.154 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 001 Starting peer:
 Version: 1.4.1-rc1
 Commit SHA: 29433f0
 Go version: go1.11.5
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Chaincode:
  Base Image Version: 0.4.15
  Base Docker Namespace: hyperledger
  Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
  Docker Namespace: hyperledger
2019-04-05 13:51:59.155 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 002 Initializing ledger mgmt
2019-04-05 13:51:59.155 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 003 Initializing ledger provider
2019-04-05 13:51:59.495 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 004 ledger provider Initialized
2019-04-05 13:51:59.791 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 005 Created state database _users
2019-04-05 13:51:59.890 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 006 Created state database _replicator
2019-04-05 13:51:59.891 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 007 ledger mgmt initialized
2019-04-05 13:51:59.891 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 008 Auto-detected peer address: 172.18.0.5:7051
2019-04-05 13:51:59.891 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 009 Returning peer0.org1.example.com:7051
2019-04-05 13:51:59.891 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 00a Auto-detected peer address: 172.18.0.5:7051
2019-04-05 13:51:59.891 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 00b Returning peer0.org1.example.com:7051
2019-04-05 13:51:59.893 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 00c Entering computeChaincodeEndpoint with peerHostname: peer0.org1.example.com
2019-04-05 13:51:59.893 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 00d Exit with ccEndpoint: peer0.org1.example.com:7052
2019-04-05 13:51:59.894 UTC [nodeCmd] createChaincodeServer -> WARN 00e peer.chaincodeListenAddress is not set, using peer0.org1.example.com:7052
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x63 pc=0x7f803c547259]

runtime stack:

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your fabric-samples, `git pull` from root of fabric-samples, and run the start.sh script again. You have the rc-1 script, which should work, but 1.4.1 officially released yesterday, can you see if the new tutorial works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sure let me check with 1.4.1.

Comment: Same issue with 1.4.1.Ran the command ./startFabric.sh javascript. I could see the error as  # Create the channel docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/h yperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configt/channel.tx Error response from daemon:Container d0249511070228331e6abbaa4eee9b34d2e0a71dd4fc08611e8cf32facea4ba is not running

Comment: Could you please help?

Comment: Referencing [https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-13419] there are some issues on some providers involving DNS resolution. Without getting into your actual system it would be difficult to figure out whether this is the issue you are seeing. I would recommend trying to a CentOS image in the cloud, or trying a different cloud provider and seeing if you still get the issue. If you share which Cloud provider, and which Image on that cloud provider you are using for Ubuntu, I would be happy to go out and try it myself.

Comment: Please find the Virtual machine details.  Its operating system version is : Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.18.0-1014-azure x86_64). This VM is hosted in Azure Cloud. You can create a Vm in Azure Cloud and just select Ubuntu Vm and try out the samples.

Comment: I will try this this afternoon, but I will say, there are quite a few Docker related issues running Ubuntu 18.04, not Fabric problems, and problems we have opened issues with Docker, one of them is a null pointer error, like you are seeing here. We don't see the same issues on U16, and we use the same Ansible Playbook to install everything on both systems.

Comment: I have got the same issue in my Laptop VMWare Ubuntu VM. Peer Node container does not start. Error Information is:  Error response from daemon: Container 0cf6cd1b3527bec5f59430ce5571be6b031dda4c2859336fc0f2327998ce77e0 is not running.... Logs of the container says..[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x63 pc=0x7f4b8c4df259]

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x1272c18, 0x2a)
 /opt/go/src/runtime/panic.go:608 +0x72
runtime.sigpanic()
 /opt/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:374 +0x2f2   .......

Comment: As mentioned  [jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-13419] . i have added "GODEBUG=netdns=go"  to the docker-compose.ymal file. This resolved my issue. Thanks lindluni for your support.